# why laraval routing return the object instead of echoing it or printing it directlly?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, routes, controller

in laravel routing we can pass a closure and it returns the result. so my question is why it cannot echo or print the result than returning it?. is it the closurity property of php or laraveles routing rule.

```
Route::get('/',function(){
    return 'hello world';
 });
```

Comment: to print the result you can use echo or dd().

Comment: but in general in laravel api you should not echo out data, you should either transform you data through an view, or return strings, objects or similar in a controller.

Answer (score 0):

Because Laravel as a framework passes the result to other functions, for example to add headers to the response. This wouldn't work if you just echoed something there.